# Proof of rank-nullity theorem starting from $Range(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

We prove rank-nullity theorem by taking a basis in Ker T and extending to the basis of $V$  and then showing that the image of the basis elements coming from the extension is a basis for Range(T). Can we do the other way ? i.e. start with a basis in Range(T) and then finding a basis in ker T.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Don't know how to start. finding elements in kernel is difficult than finding elements in range.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a linear operator $T:V\to W$. The range of $V$, being a subspace of $W$, still  has a certain relation to $V$: you can write its elements as $Tv$, $v\in V$.

However, $\ker T$, being a subspace of $V$, has no such relation to anything in $W$. The elements of $\ker T$ don't "know" anything about $W$, because they get killed before getting there. This is why you can't get a basis for $\ker T$ from any kind of construction in $W$.